# Rails routes - layout false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm building an API, and have

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  # Versioning stuff...
End
```

On that namespace, I'd like to also call `layout false` so I don't have to do it from the controller everywhere. Anyway to accomplish that?

Comment: That's not a routing job, that's a controller job.

Comment: Granted... But it seems reasonable considering what I'm trying to do, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better place for `layout false` could be `Api::ApplicationController` and then inherit from it all your Api controllers. Latter you may decide add more stuff to this controller.